# How to trans the last '_' in variable names that contain multiple '_'?

Tags: r, regex, string

this is the row name of the data I'm dealing with

```
a a_1 a_b_c_1 a_1 b_1 c_1 a_b_1
```

what I want is

```
a a_1 a.b.c_1 a_1 b_1 c_1 a.b_1
```

I tried 'gsp' and 'sp' but didn't get it.

Comment: Use look forward and look before in regex

Comment: thanks for your suggestion! but this is required by using R

Comment: Indeed. Regex is used in R. See answer by Ronak below

Comment: I only used Regex in Python before, but I just tried in R. thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace all underscore with dot except the last one.

```
x <- c('a', 'a_1', 'a_b_c_1', 'a_1', 'b_1', 'c_1', 'a_b_1')
gsub('_(?=[^_]*_)', '.', x, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "a"       "a_1"     "a.b.c_1" "a_1"     "b_1"     "c_1"     "a.b_1"
```